# Are sleeping bags needed in southern Spain in summer?

Tags: camping, sleeping-bags, temperature, hot-weather, spain

My girlfriend and I are going camping in Europe this summer and are starting off in Spain. We have [this tent](http://www.gooutdoors.co.uk/vango-banshee-200-tent-p140006), and are looking into sleeping bags. We have also been keeping an eye on the weather in Spain at night time and are wondering whether a sleeping bag is actually needed? We don't really want to spend a load of money on a sleeping bag if we're just going to melt in them.

Maybe we just don't know enough about the right sleeping bags? 
We were thinking maybe just getting sleeping mats and a small blanket.

Has anyone got any experience that could help us decide what to do?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with this question:

- Night-time temperatures vary a great deal across Spain-it is a big country, with coasts, plains and mountains
- Your ideal temperature may be very different to mine

So what you want to do is look at the range of expected temperatures in the area you plan to camp, compare those with temperatures you are comfortable with and buy accordingly.

Myself- I would want a very light sleeping bag, or some blankets unless I was up in the mountains.

Comment: At the start we will definitely be at / close to the southern coast, we might move a little inland as time goes on though..

Comment: Okay, so at the southern coast it can get cool in the evening pending on wind direction, but I would class that region as pretty warm (caveat- I am from Scotland, YMMV)

Answer (score 3):

You can find sleeping bags with a zipper, so you can open it up to a big rectangle and use it as a blanket. If it is really warm lie down on top of it.